# I want to accept the data from user input in the form table generated dynamically

Tags: python, django

I want to pass the data from user input in the template create_proposal.html. The form is inside a dynamically generated table by JavaScript. Each row has cells that have input. The table inside create_proposal.html looks like:

```
<table id="empTable" class="table-striped" border="1" cellmargin="100px" cellpadding="0px"cellspacing="5px">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <h5></h5>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h5>No.</h5>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h5>Part no.</h5>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width:30vw">
                        <h5>Description</h5>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h5>Quantity</h5>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h5>Unit Market price</h5>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <h5>Markup percentage</h5>
                    </th>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

And the script that generates the rows:

```
 <script>

    // ARRAY FOR HEADER.
    var arrHead = new Array();
    arrHead = ['', 'No.', 'Part no.', 'Description', 'Quantity', 'Unit market price', 'Markup percentage'];

    // ADD A NEW ROW TO THE TABLE.s
    function addRow() {
        var empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');

        var rowCnt = empTab.rows.length;        // GET TABLE ROW COUNT.
        var tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt);      // TABLE ROW.
        tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt);

        for (var c = 0; c < arrHead.length; c++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');          // TABLE DEFINITION.
            td = tr.insertCell(c);

            if (c == 0) {           // FIRST COLUMN.
                // ADD A BUTTON.
                var button = document.createElement('input');

                // SET INPUT ATTRIBUTE.
                button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                button.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');
                button.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-danger');

                // ADD THE BUTTON's 'onclick' EVENT.
                button.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeRow(this)');

                td.appendChild(button);
            }
            else if(c == 1){
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'number');
                ele.setAttribute('id', 'id_item_no');
                ele.setAttribute('name', 'item_no');


                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
            else if(c == 2){
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele.setAttribute('id', 'id_part_no');
                ele.setAttribute('name', 'part_no');


                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
            else if(c == 3){
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                ele.setAttribute('id', 'id_description');
                ele.setAttribute('name', 'description');


                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
            else if(c == 4){
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'number');
                ele.setAttribute('id', 'id_quantity');
                ele.setAttribute('name', 'quantity');


                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
            else if(c == 5){
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'number');
                ele.setAttribute('id', 'id_unit_market_price');
                ele.setAttribute('name', 'unit_market_price');


                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
            else if(c == 6){
                var ele = document.createElement('input');
                ele.setAttribute('type', 'number');
                ele.setAttribute('name', 'markup_percentage');
                ele.setAttribute('id', 'id_markup_percentage');

                td.appendChild(ele);
            }
        }
    }
    // DELETE TABLE ROW.
    function removeRow(oButton) {
        var empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
        empTab.deleteRow(oButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);       // BUTTON -> TD -> TR.
    }    

</script>
```

in my views.py I call a function called merge() which accepts parameters from the user input. The function in view.py that calls the merge() function looks like:

```
def resultPage(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form =createNewFinancial(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['file_name']
        organization = form.cleaned_data['organization_name']
        project_type = form.cleaned_data['project_type']
        reference = form.cleaned_data['reference_number']
        our_ref_no = form.cleaned_data['our_reference_number']
        date = form.cleaned_data['date']
        item_no = form.cleaned_data['item_no']
        part_no = form.cleaned_data['part_no']
        description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        quantity = form.cleaned_data['quantity']
        unit_market_price = form.cleaned_data['unit_market_price']
        markup_percentage = form.cleaned_data['markup_percentage']

        merge(name, organization, project_type, reference, our_ref_no, date, item_no, part_no, description, quantity, unit_market_price, markup_percentage)

return render(request, 'result.html')
```

and the merge() function:

```
def merge(name, organization, project_type, reference, our_reference, date, item_no, part_no, description, quantity, unit_market_price, markup_percentage):
template = 'master.docx'
document = MailMerge(template)

unit_price = calculateUitPrice(unit_market_price, markup_percentage)
total_price = quantity * unit_price

document.merge(
    organization = organization,
    project_type = project_type, 
    reference = reference,
    our_ref_no = our_reference,
    date = date,
)
item_table = [{
    'item_no' : str(item_no),
    'part_no' : str(part_no),
    'description' : str(description),
    'quantity' : str(quantity),
    'unit_price' : str(unit_price),
    'total_price' : str(total_price)
},]

document.merge_rows('item_no', item_table)
document.write(name+'.docx')
```

there are multiple rows that has input fields with the same id. I wanted to pass the values in an array but do not know how. Any working solution would also be nice.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using javascript to generate the form? You can just use django's forms or modelForms. Much simpler and less hassle.
If you do want to format your form differently than you can combine javascript with django forms. But always use forms.

Comment: yes but I want to add rows dynamically when a button is clicked